# Is there a fini routine for a python module written in C?

Tags: python, c, python-module

I have a python module written in C, and I would like to add a function that is called when the module is unloaded. I obviously have an `initfoo` function to initialize the module -- is there a way to tell python to call a `finifoo` function when it's uninitializing the module?

Is `atexit` my only option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in Python 2, but [Python 3 seems to](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/). If you need to manage some resource, I would advise putting it in a module-level object -- I'm pretty sure those will be garbage-collected when the module is unloaded.

---

From the link:

> Currently, extension modules are
>   initialized usually once and then
>   "live" forever. The only exception is
>   when Py_Finalize() is called: then the
>   initialization routine is invoked a
>   second time.

This suggests that you could set a static boolean in your initializer that gets flipped on every call. Check it status to see whether or not the module is being finalized.